# display value in two text box using xmlhttprequest object?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have posted the code below.
there are two files..

1. getvendorname.php
2. sales.htm (containing the javascript function)
   Here what i am did is when blur i need to retrieve the values without page reload from getvendorname.php and show the vendor name and id in the different textbox.
   Here i have to store the values into different textbox retrieved from database with the use of xmlhttprequest object.Here the values are retrieved,but i can't store into the different textbox.Its working,but it shows like this
   o/p:201anne.I need to display vendor id and vendor name on different textbox.please help me

sales.htm

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getname()
{
  var vendorID = document.getElementById("idvid").value;
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("iddiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("iddiv2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getvendorname.php?vendorid="+vendorID,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<html>
<head><title>vendor info</title> </head>
  <body>
    <td>Vendor Primary ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idvid" name="vendor_primary_number" onblur="getname()">
    </td>
    <td> <div id="iddiv1"> </div></td>
    <td> <div id="iddiv2"> </div></td>
  </body>
</html>
```

getvendorname.php

```
<?php
$vid = $_GET['vendorid'];

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('bgm_score', $connection);

$r ="select vendorid,vendorname from vendor_info where vendorid ='$vid'";
$result = mysql_query($r, $connection);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["vendorid"];
echo $row["vendorname"]; 

?>
```

Comment: I an new one to ajax please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few corrections to your code to make it work. First, replace this line:

```
document.getElementById("iddiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("iddiv1").innerHTML=vendorID;
```

The reason is you don't need to retrieve the vendor ID from the database since that's the data you're sending. Just use the variable you have. That also means you need to change your PHP code.

Remove the vendorid field from your query:

```
$r ="select vendorid,vendorname from vendor_info where vendorid ='$vid'";
```

Now it looks like this:

```
$r ="select vendorname from vendor_info where vendorid ='$vid'";
```

Also remove this line since it's not needed:

```
echo $row["vendorid"];
```